# Left Luggage Facility in Chennai International Airport (MAA)

Tags: luggage-storage, maa

I will be travelling to Chennai International Airport later this month. I have a short trip for two days around Chennai before I go to Mumbai. I will need to store away my two standard international travel suitcases for those two days instead of lugging them around with me. Is there a facility (like a cloak room) in the International terminal where I can put my luggage? If so, do I need to have an onward journey to be able to put it there? If anyone has any contact information for the facility it would be great.

I have tried to find some information online but most of it is not very clear. Every post says there is something outside the terminal itself. Is it safe to put luggage there? And also the posts are a couple of years old, and I know that the Chennai airport has undergone some huge renovations during that period.

Comment: According to the MAA website, [there is a left luggage facility](http://www.airportsindia.org.in/chennai), but unfortunately there are no details, and the page says it has not been updated since 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had to leave my baggage in the Chennai airport, so I'm contributing this for the others. (Since there were no recent answers about this with confirmed information)

There is a place to leave your luggage in the Airport. 
In Chennai airport, departures and arrivals, both international and domestic terminals are next to each other, with about 500m distance. Outside the arrivals, walk towards the other terminal. In between the terminals, there is a small room (opposite the airport) with a sign board that says "left luggage facility".

They charge INR 100 per bag (regardless of its size) per 24 hours. This price is reasonable IMO (In Delhi, the charge was INR 50 for first 4 hours and INR 5 for every hour after).

It's open 24 hours. You can drop and pick up bags anytime. Maximum time you can leave baggage is 7 days.

Comment: Multiple more recent answers indicate that this is now out-of-date, and incorrect. Downvoted.

Answer (score 7):

As of 27th August 2019, they have closed this luggage/cloakroom facility due to security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

At the Chennai International Airport, the left luggage building is in the parking lot across from arrivals.
Large bags are 100 rupees a day.
[image: left luggage building]

Comment: Greg, or any one knows if the left luggage facility shown in the picture posted by Greg is still in the same place in the parking lot across from arrivals? Also is that across the international arrivals or domestic arrivals? I am planning to arrive in chennai international airport and want to use left luggage facility or a clock room facility and need to catch a domestic flight after 6 days. Is there any left luggage facility in domestic terminal as well? Can anyone suggest keeping the luggage in domestic left luggage or international left luggage facility for my situation. I will have a cab i

Answer (score 3):

As of 7 October 2019, this facility is not available due to ongoing construction work. (as told by a airport personnel)

Answer (score 3):

As on 2Mar2020, no such facility exists - neither AAI nor some private entity. The person at the lost and found counter confirmed there is high demand for a cloakroom, and the ongoing constructions has plans for a left luggage facility.

Answer (score 2):

I used this baggage service at Chennai airport. Room is near the taxi stand. Rs 100 per day. My luggage was badly damaged by rats, however.

Comment: Multiple subsequent answers indicate that the left luggage facility at Chennai is now closed. Downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, September 2019, there is no Left Luggage facility available at both Chennai Domestic and Chennai International Airport.

Plan your journey accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Called Chennai Airport Customer Care..  This facility is not available in Chennai Airport for the past 1 year (during construction)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two options, according to [Airport-desk](http://www.airport-desk.com/airports/asia/india/chennai-international-airport.html):

- There are baggage lockers in the airport which you can safely store items in.
- Failing that, you can store them at a desk as well, and the site suggests asking at any of the information desks at the airport for where to find these.

Answer (score 1):

Now they have moved this facility to another spot close to the earlier one. The new location is in between Metro rail station and the vegetarian restaurant. At the back of the restaurant , just opposite to the Metro basement. It's a tiny one and nearly maintained. We have to show our boarding passes as a travel witness. They register our details at their log book and provide a yellow ticket. Preserve this and don't misplace/lose. IRS 100 per bag per day. Payment should be made during  the collection of baggage. Add atleast extra 30 minutes on your pre-reporting time prior to  check-in, for this process.

Answer (score 0):

I used the cloak room at the Chennai Airport in May 2017.

It is opposite to the international arrival terminal. They ask your passport/ticket as proof that you're an international traveller. Can hold your luggage for 24 hours, the price was Rs 100.

Comment: Multiple subsequent answers indicate the left luggage facility at Chennai airport is now closed. Downvoted,