# Left luggage room (cloakroom) available at Chennai Airport?

Tags: luggage-storage, chennai

Can anyone tell us whether the left luggage room (cloakroom) at Chennai Airport is available as of the 1st of April 2020?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37324/left-luggage-facility-in-chennai-international-airport-maa

Answer (score 5):

From [this article](https://www.tripsavvy.com/chennai-airport-information-guide-1539129) which was published in October 2019 says:

> Luggage can be stored at the "Left Luggage Facility" situated between the domestic and international terminals. The cost is 100 rupees per 24 hours. The maximum storage time is one week.

I don't think there is a way to pre-book this facility but I am quite confident it will be available on 1st April.